# Sentencia preparadas en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo en una consulta en `SQL`, pero no se como hacerla o pasarla en rutina `PHP`, ya que debo realizar ese reporte.

En `MySQL` me funciona perfecto, pero como hacer una rutina en `PHP` para este `query`:

```
SET @sql = NULL ;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'sum(CASE WHEN fecha = ''', fecha, ''' THEN asistencia else '''' END) AS `', fecha, '`' ) )
INTO @sql
FROM asistencia;
iSET @sql = CONCAT( 'SELECT s.dui, nombres,apellidos, codigo,nombre,depto,muni,', @sql , '
        from docentes1 c
        inner join asistencia s
          on c.dui = s.dui 
       INNER JOIN centros e
       ON c.centro = e.codigo
       AND c.sede=11117
       AND s.asistencia=1
       group by s.dui' );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Parto de la base de que entiendes algo de PHP y no sólo de MySQL.

Vamos a ver, a priori deberás utilizar una conexión PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Así podrás utilizar el PREPARED: http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements

Lo digo para que mantengas la misma ejecución, de montar el SQL, agregarle los valores, "prepararlo" y ejecutarlo.

Cualquier duda, tell me ^_^

Comment: De acuerdo @MarcTorres, probaré y compartiré lo trabajado hast ael momento

Comment: De nada, cualquier duda al respecto, aquí estamos ;)

Comment: Hola Marc, te comento que continuo teniendo problemas para ejecutar el QUERY que publiqué. He realizado la conexión con PDO

Comment: Ok, entiendo que la vonexión PDO la has hecho bien, y que has probado de hacer una select simple a cualquier tabla de las que tengas y te devuelve los resultados correctamente. Para poderte ayudar necesitaría saber más datos al respecto, que no te funciona, que error te da? Algún enlace para poder ver el error?

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomiendo que esa rutina la generes en un storeprocedure.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

luego simplemente la mandas a llamar desde php.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL mystore(:dato)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':dato',$dato);

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

como podría meter el QUERY que he publicado en la pregunta? dentro de la sentencia preparada, por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "formacion";


    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    //$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT . . . ");
```

Agradeceré me orienten como meter el siguiente QUERY a la tensentecia SQL.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN fecha = ''',
      fecha,
      ''' THEN asistencia else '''' END) AS `',
      fecha, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM asistencias_nueva1;


SET @sql
 = CONCAT('SELECT s.dui, nombres,apellidos, codigo,nombre,depto,muni,', @sql, '
            from docentes1 c
            inner join asistencias_nueva1 s
              on c.dui = s.dui 
           INNER JOIN centros e
           ON c.centro = e.codigo
           AND c.sede052017u2=12347
          AND s.unidad=2
           group by s.dui');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Mil gracias por el apoyo en esto, qu eya me está matando. :)

Comment: Para ejecutar el **Query** desde php solo tienes que usar el método que estas clocando arriba **$conn->query()** pero si ten una cosa presente ejecuta sentencia por sentencia en la misma forma que lo tienes escrito.